# If a polynomial $f(x)$ has a positive leading coefficient then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

This seems pretty intuitive-- but is there a rigorous $\epsilon-\delta$ proof for it?
I could prove $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^n=\infty$ quite easily- $x^n\geq x$ would complete the proof nicely- but when other terms are added then I don't know what to do-- thanks!

Comment: The lower degree terms are $o(x^n)$ when $x$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: Assuming that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, has degree $n$, with all the coefficients in $f(x)$ finite, you must demonstrate algebraically, that as $x \to \infty, ~[f(x) - x^n]$ *becomes trivial* when compared to $x^n$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}[a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0]=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^n[a_n+a_{n-1}x^{-1}+...+a_0x^{-n}]$

Comment: @Bernard That's just circular reasoning.

Comment: No. It's only a hint to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P_n(x)=a_nx^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + ... + a_1x + a_0 = a_nx^n( 1 + \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_nx} + ... + \frac{a_1}{x^{n-1}} + \frac{a_0}{x_n} - a_nx^n f(x).$$
We have
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1.$$
Hence
$$\lim_{x \to \infty } P_n(x)= \lim_{x \to \infty} a_nx^n = a_n\lim_{x \to \infty } x^n.$$

Answer (score 0):

One tactic is to simply factor out the largest power of $x$. Then we have $x^n(1+c_1x^{-1}+c_2x^{-2}...)$. Then argue that the part in the parentheses goes to $1$. From there, you can make an argument along the lines of "the limit of the product is the product of the limits", but you have to make sure that you are doing so under conditions that this is valid. Another way to progress is to argue that since the sum goes to $1$, there is some $x_0$ such that if $x>x_0$, then the sum is greater than $0.5$. Then you have $f(x) > 0.5x^n$.